# Can Steam be prevented from updating itself on Mac?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, macos

Is there a way to tell Steam on Mac to not update itself when it hasn't been manually launched?

I have now seen problems with this on two MacBooks. Without even trying to run Steam for anything, suddenly the system slows to a crawl, sometimes the entire screen even goes black, other programs I'm using stall with the wait timer icon, and then a progress dialog appears showing how far my unwanted Steam update is progressing.

Short of deleting Steam, is there a way to make it not update itself when not being used?

Comment: Do you let Steam launch on startup? Since it's just a program like any other, not a system process of some kind, I can't imagine how it could be running itself otherwise.

Comment: I ran the Steam installer without noticing that I had any control over whether to let Steam launch on startup. Is there a place to tell it not to load on startup? When it's running in the background, is there a place to tell it to stop once it is loaded?

Comment: Normal Mac programs can't run in the background, so just switch to it and ⌘Q or use the menu to quit. I'll write up a proper answer with a screenshot of how to prevent it from launching on startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steam's option to launch on startup is on by default. You can change it by going to the menu bar and choosing **Steam** → **Preferences…** to open Steam's Preferences window. Then in the Preferences window choose **Interface** (I know, that's not intuitive, is it), and uncheck **Run Steam when my computer starts**:

[image: Steam Preferences window with a freehand circle around the "Run Steam when my computer starts" option]

To stop an already-running Steam, just switch to its window and quit using the menu (**Steam** → **Quit**) or the Quit keyboard shortcut (⌘Q).